# Flow type 0.53.1 performance issue

Tags: flowtype

After I switched to flow-type 0.53.1 I am running into performance issues. The flow server can take a very long time to rerun after a file has been saved. Even running `flow check` is faster than waiting for the flow server to finish (in most cases).

This is the log file created by Flow in my tmp folder. As you can see it takes more than a minute to go from `Merging` to `Status: Error`.

```
[2017-08-30 14:16:24] Merge prep
[2017-08-30 14:16:24] Calculating dependencies
[2017-08-30 14:16:25] Merging
[2017-08-30 14:16:25] sending (1 errors) and (warnings from 0 files) to 0 subscribed clients (of 0 total)
^[[1;9[2017-08-30 14:17:30] Done
[2017-08-30 14:17:30] sending (1 errors) and (warnings from 38 files) to 0 subscribed clients (of 0 total)
[2017-08-30 14:17:30] sending (1 errors) and (warnings from 38 files) to 0 subscribed clients (of 0 total)
[2017-08-30 14:17:31] Status: Error
```

This is the output from running `flow check --profile`

```
TimingEvent `InitLibs`: start_wall_age: 0.856451; wall_duration: 1.657676; cpu_usage: 0.284748; flow_cpu_usage: 0.118370
TimingEvent `CommitModules`: start_wall_age: 2.514193; wall_duration: 0.042458; cpu_usage: 0.848485; flow_cpu_usage: 0.080458
TimingEvent `ResolveRequires`: start_wall_age: 2.556713; wall_duration: 0.056049; cpu_usage: 0.891304; flow_cpu_usage: 0.663143
TimingEvent `Infer`: start_wall_age: 2.612818; wall_duration: 0.000013; cpu_usage: 0.000000; flow_cpu_usage: 0.000000
TimingEvent `MakeMergeInput`: start_wall_age: 2.612846; wall_duration: 0.000202; cpu_usage: 0.000000; flow_cpu_usage: 0.000000
cycle detected among the following files:

... here it logs a log of js files from my project

TimingEvent `CalcDeps`: start_wall_age: 2.613083; wall_duration: 0.013890; cpu_usage: 0.888889; flow_cpu_usage: 0.178922
merged (strict) in 3.060765
TimingEvent `Merge`: start_wall_age: 2.627020; wall_duration: 3.061898; cpu_usage: 0.786356; flow_cpu_usage: 0.619700
minor_collections: 645
major_collections: 17
compactions:       1

minor_words:    165073829
promoted_words:  12674407
major_words:     19604089

top_heap_words: 13860352
heap_words:     13860352
live_words:     12298028
free_words:      1552671
largest_free:    1387577
fragments:          9653

live_blocks: 2964245
free_blocks: 33190
```

The flow command hangs on:

```
flow is rechecking; this should not take long [processing]
```

Comment: Oh yikes, that's really unfortunate. Sorry to hear the new version is causing you that much trouble. It's going to be tricky to do anything about this unless we have a way to reproduce. Is the codebase where this happens available publicly? Or would you be willing to screenshare with me so we can try to reduce the problem?

Comment: The codebase is not public. Would be willing to screen share.

Comment: Cool, send me an email and let's set up a time! asolove@gmail.com